# MongoDB with Mongoose - What is the difference between collection.bulkWrite and runCommand?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using MongoDB with Mongoose and currently wondering what are the difference, if I understand well reanding the doc: [runCommand](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/) and [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/).

If I understand well, one is generalist -runCommand-, the other is specialized in write operations -bulkWrite.

Maybe  there is other differences?

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: Is this a mongoose specific question?

Comment: it depent what you mean by "specific"? in Mongoose seems you can acces collection methods of MongoDB too.

Comment: No, it depends on what YOU mean by tagging this question with mongoose.

Comment: Yes I want to use theses MongoDB command in Mongoose